# placeholder not showing the same color in firefox

Tags: css, webkit

I have a below form. place holder is not having the same color in firefox as chrome or EDGE, i tried these css tricks:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: white;
}

 ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: white;
}

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: white;
}

 :-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Full Name" name="fname" required="required" id="fname">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Father's Name" name="lname" id="lname" required="required">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Office Address" name="offAddress" id="offAddress" required="required">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Mobile Number" name="Mnum" id="Mnum" required="required">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

still not working any idea? i searched a lot and didn't found the right solution plus i am new to front-end development thank you in advance

Comment: i thhink your  browser has old version..!

Comment: no firefox is up to date! @Bhargav

Comment: check version of firefox

Comment: because is same display in my both browser

Comment: Version 56.0.2 (64-bit)    Firefox is up to date @Bhargav

Comment: which color display in firefox

Comment: I see exactly the same thing in both browsers.

Comment: gray i need them to be white i have a blue backgroud color on chrome it showing white but on firefox gray

Comment: i think you reload your page `ctrl+shift+r`

Answer (score 2):

its come from your `bootstrap file`

write `css code with !important` so its work

like: `color: blue !important;`

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: blue !important;
}

 ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: blue !important;
}

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: blue !important;
}

 :-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Full Name" name="fname" required="required" id="fname">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Father's Name" name="lname" id="lname" required="required">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Office Address" name="offAddress" id="offAddress" required="required">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Mobile Number" name="Mnum" id="Mnum" required="required">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Or don't use `!important`, but set a more accurate selector in your file. The more accurate the selector is, the higher is its rules' priority.

Answer (score 0):

Just add place holder rules with class name

```css
#myForm {
  background: #333;
}
.form-control.inputCustom {
  background: transparent;
}
.form-control.inputCustom::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color:white;
}
.form-control.inputCustom::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color:white;
}
.form-control.inputCustom:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color:white;
}
.form-control.inputCustom:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
                <input type="text" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Full Name" name="fname" required="required" id="fname">
                <input type="text" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Father's Name" name="lname" id="lname" required="required">
                <input type="text" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Office Address" name="offAddress" id="offAddress" required="required">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control inputCustom " placeholder="Mobile Number" name="Mnum" id="Mnum" required="required">
            </div>
```